# How to use code to handle 'onClick' of button in a custom toolbar in multiple activities

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have a custom toolbar I have used in multiple activities (over 50 activities). The toolbar has an 'SOS' button. To add functionality to the 'SOS' button, one way would be to write same code for it's functionality in all my activities where I have used the custom toolbar.
I would like to have my code for the functionality for toolbar 'SOS' button written only once. 
Is it possible to do this (by using a custom java file or something)?

An example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by:

declare the onClick in XML of custom toolbar on button you want to perform the action

```
android:onClick="sosClick"
```

and then declare sosClick method into the BaseClass like this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass extends AppCompatActivity {

      public void sosClick(View view) {
            //Write your action here
            //Toast.makeText(this, "SOS Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

}
```

Comment: Will there be no 'onCreate()' in this custom activity?

Comment: No, it's not mandatory to declare onCreate in BaseClass But your every activity extends the BaseClass.

Comment: I need to add other functionalities too, for which I need an 'onCreate()' method. Is  it okay to inflate my custom toolbar XML in this onCreate()?

Comment: I need to display the 'SOS' (which is ImageView) on the toolbar only if the booking status of the user is active, i.e if his booking date has not ended before today.
For this, I have to get the current date and see if it is within the CheckIn and CheckOut date.
(My app is an accomodation management app).

Comment: That you can implement by making public method in BaseClass and call that method in onCreate method of every Activity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178926/discussion-between-sunny-and-lemmy).

Comment: I solved the problem using the way I mentioned earlier. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Create a Class Name **BaseActivity** & Extend it with **AppCompatActivity**
now extend your all activities with base activity and add this method in your BaseActivity

```
 public void SOSButtonClick(View view) {
        //Write your action here
  }
```